# Angular cannot install new dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Hello I using the angular application, I have installed the few dependencies such as [jwt-decoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode)
if I install any other dependencies from npm it will remove the **jwt-decoder**, If I install **jwt-decoder** it will remove the new dependencies .

all the new imports gives error (module not found).

what could be the actual problem in the application. I have used this template in our application [application referencee](https://github.com/BootstrapDash/stellar-angular-free-admin-template)

this is my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css",
              "node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/lib/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/raphael/raphael.min.js",
              "node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "12mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo1:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "demo1:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo1:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "demo1:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "demo1:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "demo1",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": true //Not working in angular 8.1.1
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try installing some other package and see if same thing happens. Also check package. json file before and after installing the package, add it to the question.

Comment: check package-lock.json. If it exists try npm install after deleting package-lock.json

Comment: you need to post the package.json file, this is not the problem.  also post the package-lock.json file.  I believe there is a mismatch or you have a problem with jwt and we can't know that till you post it.

Comment: the template github application in your application reference link is an Angular 10 application. Make sure your NPM packages listed in package.json are Angular 10 core libraries and check the other third party NPM packages work with Angular 10. The libraries that are pre Angular 10 would likely give you the module not found error. Also make sure you follow the install instructions for new dependencies as some may also require importing into app.module.ts before they can be used within app components.